# Python Tkinter, problem with alignment of buttons in Notebook widget

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a problem with the Notebook-widget of Python's Tkinter-module when aligning buttons.

I don't understand how to achieve in the attached code, that in the 'text'-tab the two buttons 'previous' and 'next' stick to the lower border of the root-window, independent of the length of the text in the Message-widget.

I want to display different texts of different lengths and I want the buttons be always positioned at the lower border of the window.

Could anybody explain what I have to change in the code, please?

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("600x600")
note = Notebook(root)

tab1 = Frame(note)
tab2 = Frame(note)
tab3 = Frame(note)

temp = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et'

M1 = Message(tab1, text=temp, width=600)
M1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='n')

F1 = Frame(tab1)
F1.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='ew')

B1P = Button(F1, text='previous')
B1P.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='ew')
B1N = Button(F1, text='next')
B1N.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='ew')

F1.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
F1.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)

F1.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

note.add(tab1, text = "Text")
note.add(tab2, text = "Add")
note.add(tab3, text = "Edit")
note.grid(sticky='ns')

mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply have to position the two `Button` widgets on the `F1 Notebook Tab`, and give some padding.

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *

root = Tk()
#root.geometry("603x600")
root.resizable(0,0)
note = Notebook(root)

tab1 = Frame(note)
tab2 = Frame(note)
tab3 = Frame(note)

temp = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et'

M1 = Message(tab1, text=temp, width=600)
M1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='n')

F1 = Frame(tab1)
F1.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='ew')

# Position the buttons on the F1 tab
B1P = Button(F1, text='<< previous')
B1P.grid(row=1, column=0, pady=(100,0), sticky='ews')

B1N = Button(F1, text='next >>')
B1N.grid(row=1, column=1,pady=(100,0), sticky='ews')

F1.grid_columnconfigure((0,1), weight=1)
F1.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

note.add(tab1, text = "Text")
note.add(tab2, text = "Add")
note.add(tab3, text = "Edit")

# span two columns to position the notebook over the two buttons
note.grid(row=0, columnspan=2, sticky='s')

mainloop()
```

**Output GUI**

> Text Tab

[image: opg]

> Add Tab

[image: opg]

You can play around with the padding values. I have commented wherever changes were made. Hope you understand.

Comment: @ Somraj Chowdhury :    That is not what I wanted. The two buttons shall only be on the 'Text'-tab, not on the other tabs.

Comment: I'm sorry, please don't mind. I have made the edits. Ask if you have doubts and please comment if this is still not answering your question.

Comment: @ Somraj Chowdhury: Never mind. And thank you very much for your help. You made my day. I have tried to find a solution for several hours.